# Close outer container from Internet with iptables

Tags: networking, iptables, docker

How to close exact docker container port (for example 7777) from access from Internet with iptables. But the other containers should be reachable.

Comment: try the solution on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53843777/9618184

Answer (score 0):

You can set `iptables` rules to block incoming traffic on port 7777

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 7777 -j REJECT
```

If you don't want the outside user from getting an ICMP response then you can `DROP` instead:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 7777 -j DROP
```

Comment: I've already tried this but it doesn't work for Docker containers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we're talking about containers on the default docker network (docker0) here.

By default docker containers are not accessible from outside the docker host, however in the default docker-engine configuration where inter-container communication is enabled (--icc=true), containers on the default network can see each others ports so shouldn't need any special configuration to get access.

So the answer is that in a default docker-engine install what you're describing should just work, if your configuration differs some additional detail on what you're doing would be useful.